# Multiple close votes in valid questions from the same user

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

When going to the review queue for Close Votes noticed various good questions from one particular user being VTC. The questions are

- [How do those who reject Q explain Matthew 5:38-48 and Luke 6:27-36?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/46776/27054)
- [In what sense is Ammon not remembered among the nations?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/44171/27054)
- [Does the Canaanite woman disagree with Jesus in Matthew 15:27?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/19886/27054)
- [Does the narrator of Numbers assert that the Anakim come from the Nephilim?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/41951/27054)

Not sure what lead the user who did it to target this one particular user and not entirely sure if that would be something relevant to figure out.

How shall one deal with this situation apart from voting to "Leave Open"?

Comment: I also got downvotes on those four questions within the space of 4 minutes. Someone wanted to retaliate for some reason? I'm not worried though, the votes will probably be reversed automatically, and one person's close votes aren't enough to matter, and if 4 other people agree with closing them, then the questions probably need improving!

Comment: I guess it wasn't enough downvotes to trigger the scripts as they weren't reverted :/

Comment: I had a whole series of downvotes recently (last week, I think it was) on BH but the system noticed it and reversed most or all of them. Someone is evidently not happy.